# error when calling virtual destructor using a function pointer in VC 6.0

Tags: c++

i want to see the content of the vtable of the class A, especially the virtual desctructor, but i can not call it through a function pointer.
Here is my code:

```
typedef void (*fun)();


class A {
public:
     virtual func() {printf("A::func() is called\n");}
     virtual ~A() {printf("A::~A() is called\n");}
};

//enter in the vtable 
void *getvtable (void* p, int off){
     return (void*)*((unsigned int*)p+off);
}

//off_obj is used for multiple inherence(so not here), off_vtable is used to specify the   position of function in vtable
fun getfun (A* obj, unsigned int off_obj,int off_vtable){
     void *vptr = getvtable(obj,off_obj);
     unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)vptr;
     p += sizeof(void*) * off_vtable;
     return (fun)getvtable(p,0);
}


void main() {
     A* ptr_a = new A;
     fun pfunc = getfun(ptr_a,0,0);
     (*pfunc)();
     pfunc = getfun(ptr_a,0,1);
     (*pfunc)(); //error occurred here, this is supposed to be the virtual desctrutor, why?
}
```

Comment: What's your compiler, and what exactly do you think happens when you call a destructor without passing an object to be destructed somehow?

Comment: A destructor does not return a void. The definition of function pointer fun cannot hold the address of a destructor as there is a type mismatch.

Comment: Ram is right, but the compiler said "ok"

Comment: @pltc325: The compiler usually says "ok" to a `reinterpret_cast` (or the even more dangerous C-style casts that you're using). That doesn't mean that the conversion is valid, it just means that you've told it to go ahead and force the conversion whether it makes sense or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose for the sake of argument that the vtable in question really is laid out the way you think it is, as a table of ordinary memory addresses, and that when casting those addresses to function pointers, they're callable.

You have at least two problems:

1. The *calling convention* for the member functions isn't necessarily the same as for ordinary functions. Microsoft's default calling convention is *thiscall*, which places a pointer to the object whose method is being called in the ECX register. There's no facility for specifying that manually; the only way to make that happen is by calling a member function *in the way member functions are called*, which involves syntax like `obj.f()` or `pobj->f()`. You can't do that with pointers to functions (not even member-function pointers), unless you write machine code or assembler to get all the low-level details right.

   You happen not to hit this problem for `func` because it doesn't make reference to `this` (either directly or by implicit reference to other members). The destructor does, though. Destructors are special, and what's actually stored in the vtable is a pointer to a compiler-generated helper function that calls the real destructor and then checks some flags passed as a hidden parameter to determine whether it should free the object's memory. The value that happens to be in ECX doesn't matter for the `func` call, but it's very important to be right for the `~A` call.
2. Destructors aren't like normal functions. As I mentioned above, the compiler can generate one or more helper functions, and they receive parameters in addition to `this`. You haven't accounted for that in your code. The compiler generates separate helpers for array and non-array destructors, so right now we don't even know which one you found at index 1 of the vtable. But since you didn't pass it a valid flag parameter, and there's no way to pass it the `this` value, it doesn't really matter what you find in the vtable anyway.

You can attempt to solve the first problem by specifying a different calling convention, like *stdcall*. That puts the `this` parameter back on the stack with the rest of the parameters, and that allows you to pass it when you call the function pointer. For `func`, `fun` would need to have a declaration like this:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * fun)(A*);
```

Invoke `pfunc` like this:

```
pfunc(ptr_a);
```

To solve the second problem, you'll need to determine the actual order of the vtable functions so you know to find the right destructor helper. And to call it, you'd need a different function-pointer declaration, too. Destructors don't technically have a return type, but `void` works well enough. You could use something like this:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * destr)(A*, unsigned flags);
```

For most of this answer, I've used [an article by Igorsk](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) about recognizing certain patterns in a program for the purpose of decompiling it back into C++. Part 2 covers classes.

Comment: I can now get destructor by using "typedef void (__stdcall * fun)(A*)". When i used it to get a normal member function, it prompted an error about wrong call convetion, and "typedef void (__stdcall * destr)(A*, unsigned flags); " cant get the destructr neither. Why?

Comment: You have to change the calling conventions in the declarations of the member functions, too. `virtual __stdcall ~A()` If that doesn't compile, then you cannot call destructors via a function pointer because there's no way to provide the `this` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You don't call the destructor. You call operator delete(), and it figures out the destructor. Calling destructors directly is Undefined Behavior, in the same sense that dereferencing NULL is, i.e. blows up on every platform I've seen.

Comment: *Calling destructors directly is Undefined Behavior*, Not really, Only way to get an destructor called for placement new allocated object is calling it explicitly.So the statement is misleading.Calling destructors for local/automatic allocated objects is indeed an dangerous idea, however the act itself does not cause an Undefined Behavior, its the actions that follow after the act.

Comment: Calling the destructor is not undefined behaviour as @Als says. You just have to be very careful and understand that after the call, the destructed object is "off-limits".